# Need Tkinter code for python GUI for implementation of TSP in Branch and bound and dynamic programming methods..

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Need Tkinter code for python GUI for implementation of TSP in Branch and bound and dynamic programming methods.. 
The below code is working fine and i need a gui platform for my project presentation tomorrow. 
i tried programming in tkinter but not getting along with the code. 
in the GUI i need text boxes to read no: of cities and a n*n matrix. output screen displays cost of path and optimal route. Can u guys help me with it? thanks in advance.

```
import itertools

    INF = 100000000

    best_cost = 0

def reduce(size, w, row, col, rowred, colred):
rvalue = 0
for i in range(size):
    temp = INF
    for j in range(size):
        temp = min(temp, w[row[i]][col[j]])
    if temp > 0:
        for j in range(size):
            if w[row[i]][col[j]] < INF:
                w[row[i]][col[j]] -= temp
        rvalue += temp
    rowred[i] = temp
for j in range(size):
    temp = INF
    for i in range(size):
        temp = min(temp, w[row[i]][col[j]])
    if temp > 0:
        for i in range(size):
            if w[row[i]][col[j]] < INF:
                w[row[i]][col[j]] -= temp
        rvalue += temp
    colred[j] = temp
return rvalue


def bestEdge(size, w, row, col):
mosti = -INF
ri = 0
ci = 0
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        if not w[row[i]][col[j]]:
            minrowwelt = INF
            zeroes = 0
            for k in range(size):
                if not w[row[i]][col[k]]:
                    zeroes += 1
                else:
                    minrowwelt = min(minrowwelt, w[row[i]][col[k]])
            if zeroes > 1: minrowwelt = 0
            mincolwelt = INF
            zeroes = 0
            for k in range(size):
                if not w[row[k]][col[j]]:
                    zeroes += 1
                else:
                    mincolwelt = min(mincolwelt, w[row[k]][col[j]])
            if zeroes > 1: mincolwelt = 0
            if minrowwelt + mincolwelt > mosti:
                mosti = minrowwelt + mincolwelt
                ri = i
                ci = j
return mosti, ri, ci


def explore(n, w, edges, cost, row, col, best, fwdptr, backptr):
global best_cost

colred = [0 for _ in range(n)]
rowred = [0 for _ in range(n)]
size = n - edges
cost += reduce(size, w, row, col, rowred, colred)
if cost < best_cost:
    if edges == n - 2:
        for i in range(n): best[i] = fwdptr[i]
        if w[row[0]][col[0]] >= INF:
            avoid = 0
        else:
            avoid = 1
        best[row[0]] = col[1 - avoid]
        best[row[1]] = col[avoid]
        best_cost = cost
    else:
        mostv, rv, cv = bestEdge(size, w, row, col)
        lowerbound = cost + mostv
        fwdptr[row[rv]] = col[cv]
        backptr[col[cv]] = row[rv]
        last = col[cv]
        while fwdptr[last] != INF: last = fwdptr[last]
        first = row[rv]
        while backptr[first] != INF: first = backptr[first]
        colrowval = w[last][first]
        w[last][first] = INF
        newcol = [INF for _ in range(size)]
        newrow = [INF for _ in range(size)]
        for i in range(rv): newrow[i] = row[i]
        for i in range(rv, size - 1): newrow[i] = row[i + 1]
        for i in range(cv): newcol[i] = col[i]
        for i in range(cv, size - 1): newcol[i] = col[i + 1]
        explore(n, w, edges + 1, cost, newrow, newcol, best, fwdptr, backptr)
        w[last][first] = colrowval
        backptr[col[cv]] = INF
        fwdptr[row[rv]] = INF
        if lowerbound < best_cost:
            w[row[rv]][col[cv]] = INF
            explore(n, w, edges, cost, row, col, best, fwdptr, backptr)
            w[row[rv]][col[cv]] = 0

for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        w[row[i]][col[j]] = w[row[i]][col[j]] + rowred[i] + colred[j]

#  code for branch & bound 
def bb(w,size):
global best_cost
for i in range(size):
    a[i][i]=INF
print('The cost matrix:')
for i in range(size):
    print(a[i])
col = [i for i in range(size)]
row = [i for i in range(size)]
best = [0 for _ in range(size)]
route = [0 for _ in range(size)]
fwdptr = [INF for _ in range(size)]
backptr = [INF for _ in range(size)]
best_cost = INF

explore(size, w, 0, 0, row, col, best, fwdptr, backptr)

index = 0
for i in range(size):
    route[i] = index
    index = best[index]
index = []
cost = 0

for i in range(size):
    if i != size - 1:
        src = route[i]
        dst = route[i + 1]
    else:
        src = route[i]
        dst = 0
    cost += w[src][dst]
    index.append(src+1)
index.append(1)
print('B&B Minimum cost:',cost)
print('B&B Optimal path:',index)
return

#   code for dynamic programming
def dp(A,N):
v=[x for x in range(1,N)]
s=tuple(itertools.permutations(v,N-1))

l=len(s)
C=[]
for i in range(l):
    t=s[i]
    c=A[0][t[0]]
    for j in range(1,len(t)):
        c+=A[t[j-1]][t[j]]
    c+=A[t[j]][0]
    C=C+[c]

m=min(C)
print('DP Minimum cost:',m)
d={k:p for (k,p) in zip(C,s)}
r=d[m]
r=[x+1 for x in r]
r.insert(0,1)
r.append(1)
print('DPOptimal tour:',r)
return

####    getting inputs from user
n=int(input('Enter the no.of cities:'))
a=[[0 for i in range(n)]for j in range(n)]
print('Enter the cost matrix:')
for i in range(n):
for j in range(n):
    a[i][j]=int(input())
# calling branch & bound
bb(a,n)
#calling dynamic programming
dp(a,n)
```

Comment: So what's your specific problem? Dumping 200+ lines of code and just  saying *"I need X"* isn't really a question. you question should be in the form of *"I need X, this is my code, but it's doing Y, I tried Z to solve it"*. Also, the code you pasted doesn't seem valid Python, since at a few places the indentation is messed up, so make sure you copy/pasted it correctly.

Comment: your indentation is messed up.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "GUI", I've found that throwing together a quick website using Flask is one of the easiest ways to get a GUI together.  Of course, this isn't faster if you don't know web programming.

Comment: I don't think you need this code anymore since this was posted 6 years ago, but I like your implementation of the B&B algorithm and I suggest that you post it somewhere for people to see.

Answer (score 0):

That is basically asking someone to write your application for you.

Tkinter can be hard to get a grasp of for some people but it should take no more than a few hours. If you write a separate application that just displays "hello world" when a button is pressed like you will learn [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/) then it is just a case of repeating code and making your logic fit.

The community would be happy to help you when code does not do what you think. Try go through the tutorial and then come back with your issues.

Just a side note: Put more whitespace/comments in your code when posting, it will make answers much faster and relevant.